# Participation of DC component in total average power of signal

Tags: power, dc, components

My task is to calculate participation (in percent) of DC component in total average power of signal from photo:

[image]

I represented this signal as complex Fourier series: $$u(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=-\infty,n\neq 0}^{n=\infty}\frac{1}{2n\pi}e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{jn*500t}.$$

Average power of signal is calculated using formula $$P=\lim_{T->\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{\tau}^{\tau+T}(f(t))^{2}dt$$ but how should I use it here? And how to calculate participation of DC component? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is likely asking you to recall [Parseval's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity), which is stated as

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |c_n|^2 = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 \, dx$$

where \$c_n\$ are the coefficients of the Fourier series of a periodic function \$f(x)\$ with period \$2\pi\$.

You can see that the right-hand side of the identity is proportional to the average power of the signal. So, with some manipulation of the scaling factors, you can use this to assign a portion of the power of the single to each of the fourier components.

Note 1: I assume that your signal repeats on every interval of time *T* (that is, \$f(t+T)=f(t)\$). The way you've drawn it,it looks like the signal is 0 outside the region \$0 < t < T\$, but that would make it a non-periodic signal and it wouldn't make sense to talk about its Fourier series representation or average power.

Note 2: Notice that in your formula for the average power, you are have two different variables named *T*. One which you take to the limit of infinity, and one built in to the definition of the function *f*. Since *f* is periodic with period *T*, you don't need to take a limit and you can just use

$$ P = \dfrac{1}{T}\int_\tau^{\tau+T} f^2(t)\, dt$$

for any \$\tau\$ of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for reply! It's repeating, I just didn't draw it :) I will try to solve it now using your suggestions

Comment: Here is how I tried it:
Average power of periodic signal can be calculated using relation $$Ptotal=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}|Fn|^{2}.$$ Using Parseval's theorem, it is equal to $$\frac{1}{T}\int_{\tau}^{\tau +T}(f(t))^{2}dt.$$ For my signal, $$Ptotal=\frac{1}{T}\int_{\tau}^{\tau +T}(f(t))^{2}dt=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}(\frac{Et}{T})^{2}dt=\frac{E}{T^{3}}\frac{T^{3}}{3}=\frac{E}{3} (E=1)=\frac{1}{3}.$$ For DC component I have:$$\frac{1}{T}Pdc=\int_{0}^{T}(\frac{1}{2})^{2}dt=\frac{1}{4}.$$ Is it ok?

Comment: So contribution of DC component is 75%